# Plural Form Help? (What are the forms of девочка)

Tags: словоупотребление

Здравствуйте! 
I am currently learning the Russian language via Rosetta Stone, and am currently very confused as I cannot tell the difference between девочек and девочки. I have no idea what the first form means (I know both mean girl), and I previously thought that the second form meant girls. Can anyone tell me what the specific differences are between девочка, девочек, and девочки (and possibly any other forms that I could come across in the future). 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are six grammatical cases in Russian. Simply put:

```
Case           Singular     Plural

Nominative     девочка      девочки
Genitive       девочки      девочек
Dative         девочке      девочкам
Accusative     девочку      девочек
Instrumental   девочкой     девочками
Prepositional  [о] девочке  [о] девочках
```

Yes, the words for singular genitive and plural nominative coincide and have the same pronunciation (not always, but for the word `девочка` this is the case) so usually the context should determine which form is used.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot. However, I do not understand what you mean by "[o]".

Comment: It is a prepositional case, and usually the word is preceeded by preposition "o" (in brackets). I remember that back in school it was even preceeded by "думаю о" - "думаю о *девочке/девочках*"

Comment: The prepositional case of a noun in Russian only occurs after certain prepositions (with certain meanings), so in some dictionaries the grammatical tables always insert the preposition o in front of words in the prepositional case. I always thought this was sort of dumb, because it's not as if all the other noun cases can be used by themselves.  Everything needs a context when used in real situations, so why the need for the crutch of sticking o in front of prepositional case nouns in a grammatical table? For instance, the website викисловарь does not use o in the prepositional case for nouns.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than displaying for you the forms of *девочка*, let me tell you how to look for the forms of many words, say, you are interested now in *человек*. Then you go to, say, Wiktionary and do the direct search or type:

```
 https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/человек
```

The forms appear.